# Iterating through a list of view models and calculating values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an `AddToCart` action method which adds products to a cart via ajax, it basically works fine but sometimes (I cannot pinpoint it) e.g. I add a few products from one category, and then a few from another and the total doubles, so e.g. if I add 3 from one category, and then 1 from another it will be 4, and then again it will be 10! And then it will go on as normal.

Can you see what is wrong with this code?

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(string id)
        {
            List<CartVM> cartVMList = new List<CartVM>();
            CartVM cartVM = new CartVM();

            int productId = Int32.Parse(id);
            int qty = 0;
            decimal price2 = 0;

            Db db = new Db();

            var result = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId);
            decimal price = result.Price;

            cartVM.ProductId = productId;
            cartVM.Quantity = 1;
            cartVM.Price = price;

            if (Session["cart"] != null)
            {
                cartVMList = (List<CartVM>)Session["cart"];
                var itemToEdit = cartVMList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductId == productId);
                if (itemToEdit == null)
                {
                    cartVMList.Add(cartVM);
                }
                else
                {
                    itemToEdit.Quantity++;
                }

                foreach (var item in cartVMList)
                {
                    qty += item.Quantity;
                    price2 += item.Quantity * item.Price;
                }

                cartVM.Quantity = qty;
                cartVM.Price = price2;

            }
            else
            {
                cartVMList.Add(cartVM);
                Session["cart"] = cartVMList;
            }

            return PartialView(cartVM);

        }
```

Basically the `if (Session["cart"] != null)` part is the meat of it and where the problem is I presume.

Comment: I don't think a single `Action` is supposed to work with multiple VM's, are you sure your VM isn't just wrong. From what you describe it seems like you want a `CartVM` which holds all the `Products` and their `Quantities`, instead of each `CartVM` holding a single product and it's quantity.

Comment: Didn't understand this part of code.
foreach (var item in cartVMList)
                {
                    qty += item.Quantity;
                    price2 += item.Quantity * item.Price;
                }

                cartVM.Quantity = qty;
                cartVM.Price = price2;

You sum everything on newly edited item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method contains a lot of unnecessary things and can be simplified a lot:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int productId)
{
    // get a cart from session or create new
    var cart = Session["cart"] as List<CartVM> ?? new List<CartVM>();

    using(var db = new Db())
    {
        // get product in question
        var product = db.Products
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId)

        // if this is unknown product, throw exception
        if(product == null)
        {
            thrown new ArgumentException("Invalid product", nameof(productId));
        }

        // get existing line
        var existingCartLine = cart
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductId == productId);

        // if there was no existing line, add a new one
        if(existingCartLine == null)
        {
            cart.Add(new CartVM
            {
                ProductId = product.Id,
                Quantity = 1,
                Price = product.Price,
                TotalPrice = product.Price
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // otherwise modify existing line
            existingCartLine.Quantity++;
            existingCartLine.TotalPrice = cartLine.Price * cartLine.Quantity;
        }
    }

    // save cart back in the session
    Session["cart"] = cart;

    // return view
    return PartialView(cart);
}
```

Comment: I think this is working. I've had to modify this code a bit because I do actually need both a single VM and a list of them but with this cleaner code all together it seems that the bug is gone, will test it more thoroughly in a bit and get back to you.